# "Wi-fi is disabled by hardware switch" with TL-WN722N card on Lenovo T400, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, lenovo

my builtin wi-fi card went down, so I bought TP-LINK TL-WN722N (a USB one).

It worked straight away with Windows XP, but it did not with Ubuntu 14.04 as the driver was missing. I installed ath9k driver from backports-3.18.1 and it seems to be recognized.

I can see it listed as wlan1 when running `ifonfig all`:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:7e:14:c8:0a  
          inet addr:10.9.20.25  Bcast:10.9.20.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:7eff:fe14:c80a/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3853 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3301354 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:639405 (639.4 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fa400000-fa420000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:561 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:561 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:79287 (79.2 KB)  TX bytes:79287 (79.2 KB)

wlan1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:f2:6d:0c:2a:6b  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

When I execute `ifconfig wlan1 up` the green control light on the device lights up, so it clearly reacts.

When I exexcute `rfkill list` I get the following output:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

So it looks like I have a hard block on my builtin network card, but I do not have one on my USB adapter.

Still [here's what I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BEdp7.png) in the network manager - it still claims that the adapter is disabled by hardware switch and so I cannot connect to any network.

Any hints on what can be done?

Comment: What is the driver for the internal device? It is possible that if we blacklist it, the hard block may go away. `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 5100 
                 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection [8086:4237]
                 Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1211]
                 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you try blacklisting the internal device to see if it helps:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist iwlwifi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r iwlwifi
exit
rfkill list all
```

It may take a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

try this [tape trick to mask a pin](https://youtu.be/yzAKcmlaH1M) only after - if the problem still persists after trying the other solutions such as unblock -

> sudo rfkill unblock wifi
>
> sudo rfkill unblock all

command. In my laptop the same problem had occurred and I myself applied the trick and since then my WiFi works like charm.

Comment: Actually, I already tried `rfkill unblock` to no effect. Please take a note that according to `rfkill list` output there's neither soft nor hard block on my USB adapter, which is the one I am willing to use (although GUI indicator says there is one).

As for the pin trick - as I mentioned I am using TP-LINK TL-WN722N USB adapter so it is clearly not a solution there.

Comment: for build in network card the [link](https://youtu.be/yzAKcmlaH1M) i have already provided by i can't say about usb adapter. I also had bought one when the issue was there in my pc. The GUI is showing same as yours but I corrected my internal network adapter and it wifi worked but i didn't check whether usb adapter worked or not (now i have given to someone as there was no need for it)